# transpose sets of three rows to columns

Tags: text-processing

I have a file that has below entries:

```
[root@ovmm329 ovm_utils]# cat /tmp/disk.txt
Physical Disk : 'IBM (67) device=/dev/mapper/360050768018206483000000000000453 shareddisk=true
Physical Disk : 'IBM (58) device=/dev/mapper/36005076801820648300000000000043f shareddisk=true
Physical Disk : 'IBM (59) device=/dev/mapper/360050768018206483000000000000440 shareddisk=true
Physical Disk : 'IBM (71) device=/dev/mapper/360050768018206483000000000000497 shareddisk=true
[root@ovmm329 ovm_utils]#
```

I tried using sed and awk in all possible way which I am aware of but couldn't get it in the required format. I would like to have the file in this format:

```
Physical Disk  device                                          Shareddisk
IBM (67)        /dev/mapper/360050768018206483000000000000453  true
IBM (58)        /dev/mapper/36005076801820648300000000000043f  true
IBM (59)        /dev/mapper/360050768018206483000000000000440  true
IBM (71)        /dev/mapper/360050768018206483000000000000497  true
```

Comment: Does this: `awk -F [:\'] '{print $3}' infile` solve your need?

Comment: The format of disk.txt is changing. Is the current value correct?

Comment: Thank you for the help Binary and Jecxjo your suggestion worked and helped me to get the data in the required format.

Comment: Binary, awk -F [:\'] '{print $3}' infile this didn't helped but i believe this will be helpful for me in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk variables and multiple matches you can read each line, store what you need and then print on the last match and start over.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  DISK=""
  DEVICE=""
  FS=" : "
  print "Physical Disk\tdevice\t\t\t\t\t\tShareddisk"
  }

/Physical Disk/ {
  DISK=$2
  FS="="
}

/device/ {
  DEVICE=$2
}

/shareddisk/ {
  print DISK "\t" DEVICE "\t" $2
  FS=" : "
  }
```

Then run the script against your file `awk -f ./script.awk ./disk.txt`

```
$ awk -f ./parse.awk ./disk.txt
Physical Disk   device                                          Shareddisk
'IBM (67)       /dev/mapper/360050768018206483000000000000453   true
'IBM (58)       /dev/mapper/36005076801820648300000000000043f   true
'IBM (59)       /dev/mapper/360050768018206483000000000000440   true
'IBM (71)       /dev/mapper/360050768018206483000000000000497   true
```

To break down the script, it starts with a `BEGIN` block which is run at the start. It defines some variables and sets the Field Separator `FS` and prints the header. The first match is for `Physical Disk` and stores the disk name to a variable. The Field Separator is changed to `=` since the Device and Shared Disk lines use `=`. When the line matching `/shareddisk/` is hit the variables are printed and the Field Separator is changed again to match the next Physical Disk line.

**Edit**

This assumes the format of the file is:

```
cat disk.txt
Physical Disk : 'IBM (67)
  device=/dev/mapper/360050768018206483000000000000453
  shareddisk=true
Physical Disk : 'IBM (58)
  device=/dev/mapper/36005076801820648300000000000043f
  shareddisk=true
Physical Disk : 'IBM (59)
  device=/dev/mapper/360050768018206483000000000000440
  shareddisk=true
Physical Disk : 'IBM (71)
  device=/dev/mapper/360050768018206483000000000000497
  shareddisk=true
```